# Tornado context manager called in gen.coroutine

Tags: python, twisted, tornado, coroutine

I am working now with AMQP pika library. What I want to develop is context manager or decorator that ensures connection establishment to Rabbit. The problem that it is impossible to use generators inside decorators because they must return called function. The following example raises an exception:

```
def ensure_conn(func):

    @gen.coroutine
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        yield self.connection.ensure_connection()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

There is almost the same problem with context managers. it is impossible to use yield two  times. The following example raises exception that generator does not stopped.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
@gen.coroutine
def ensure_conn(self):
    yield self.ensure_connection()
    yield
```

Please recommend another approach ? Of course I am already satisfied with simple coroutine's calls. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to yield twice in the second example?

Comment: Thank You @Michael0x2a. By looking through the source code of contextlib.contextmanager I understood that it calls next on generator function (ensure_conn) being at \__enter\__ method. As we now .next() on gen trasfers execution context inside `with`statement. In \__exit\__ method it ensures that generator has stopped normally. However in my case self.ensure_connection is tornado coroutine that returns future object. By yielding it, gen.coroutine decorator transfers execution context from that point and waits while future object will be ready to return a value (answer).

Comment: Why is this tagged "twisted"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are two ways to create a context manager, that ensures something to you. In my case it was connection to AMQP. The first way is to override `concurrent.futures.Future` `result()` method, forcing it to return a generator function decorated by `contextlib.contextmanager`. [ajdavis](https://github.com/ajdavis) used this approach in his nice library [TORO](https://github.com/ajdavis/toro/). You can see it by navigating to [this line](https://github.com/ajdavis/toro/blob/master/toro/__init__.py#L109).

However, if you don't want to override `concurrent.futures.Future` object, then I recommend you walk through the following snippet:

```
@gen.coroutine
def ensure_connection(*args, **kwargs):
    res = yield _make_connection(timeout=kwargs.pop('timeout', 5), *args, **kwargs)
    raise gen.Return(res)

@gen.coroutine
def ensure(*args, **kwargs):
    res = yield ensure_connection(*args, **kwargs)

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def func(res):
       try:
          yield  # your wrapped code
       finally:
          pass

    return func(res)

@gen.coroutine
def simple_usage(conn):
    with (yield conn.ensure()) as res:
        # Do your target staff here

conn = ...
IOLoop.add_callback(callback=lambda : simple_usage(conn))
```

Comment: I think it should be: raise gen.Return(func(res)) instead of return func(res), unless Python 3.